# Is there a way to purge a dynamoDB stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am working with dynamodb stream and lambda triggers over them. I've got myself into a fix as my lambda reads records from TRIM_HORIZON and it failed to process the very first record. Now the lambda is hell-bent on retrying the processing of that specific record. Is there a way to purge the stream so that new records start flowing and they can be processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want **new records** (those coming in now, rather than historical records), use **LATEST** instead of *TRIM_HORIZON*.

As to answer the question, there is no way to purge a Kinesis/DynamoDb stream yet.

Comment: Hi John, If I start reading from LATEST record the stream still holds historical records and my application will eventually break on consuming the first record. I have fixed my issue from the application itself but I still wanted to know if there was a way to purge the DynamoDBStream completely.

Comment: There does not appear to be a delete/purge capability for a Kinesis / DynamoDB stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to purge the dynamo stream. One work around is to delete the stream and recreate it. (Highly not recommended in production as that incurs data loss)